# Can't POST, 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: javascript, php

I wrote a simple code:
login page, and i'm trying to send the username to php page.

when i click submit on the login page, i received 405 Method Not Allowed.

If i'm using get method - it's working, but i want post because i want to send user and pass to the server not in the address.

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="mainjs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input id="fname" type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input id="lname" type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="testfunc();">
</form> 

<div id='result'></div>
<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "action_page.php".</p>

</body>
```

```
JavaScript:

function testfunc(){
    alert("MainJS");
    var fname = $('#fname').val();
    var lname = $('#lname').val();

    $.post('getdata.php', {fname:fname, lname:lname}, function(data){
        alert(data);
        $('#result').html(data);
    });
}
```

PHP File:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
    echo "Success";
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could not replicate your issue with the 405 Method Not Allowed message, but I have a feeling it has to do with those headers you are sending in your PHP file. I'm not sure why you were sending those, as I don't see the reason to do so for what you are trying to accomplish.

If you really need to send those headers from the PHP file, this answer may not help. I tried the steps below and was able to get what I believe is your desired functionality.

First, lets move your scripts to right before the closing body tag:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="mainjs.js"></script>
</body>
```

Then, lets remove the onclick and give that submit button an id that we can grab from JavaScript instead:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

Next, in the mainjs.js file, you should select that submit button, then add an event listener to it with the contents of your old testfunc():

```
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');

submit.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("MainJS");
  var fname = $('#fname').val();
  var lname = $('#lname').val();

  $.post('getdata.php', {fname:fname, lname:lname}, function(data){
      alert(data);
      $('#result').html(data);

  });
});
```

Notice that an 'event' is passed as a parameter to the anonymous event handler function in addEventListener. You must call preventDefault() on this event so that the form doesn't submit, which reloads the whole page.

I'm not sure what you were doing in your PHP file, but here is my getdata.php:

```
<?php

if ($_REQUEST['fname'] == 'Mickey' && $_REQUEST['lname'] == 'Mouse') {
  $username = 'Disney';
  echo $username;
}
```

You of course should change that to whatever username lookup scheme you have devised. When I click submit, I see 'Disney' appear on the HTML page inside of your #result div, which I think is your desired functionality.